# OSGi Configuration Admin Service in Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: java, configuration, osgi, netbeans-platform

We are developing a Netbeans RCP application that includes NB modules, and OSGi modules. We are trying to use config admin service within our OSGi modules. Our basic goal is to get a osgi module's configuration from a config property file via OSGi admin service.

But we don't have been able to read our config property file even if we tried possible file locations( under user dir, osgi run dir etc...). We have also tried to set up felix but no success.

It should be very helpful, if someone can guide use how to place config property file to an appropriate location and get it read by config admin service.

Netbeans version is 7.3.1 and we run in Windows 8 64 bit.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The way to set the properties for a configuration admin service is actually by means of the configuration admin interface itself. How the configurations are stored is up to the service and not necessarily via property files. Therefore, the way to go, if you want to follow the specifications, is to let a bundle load the property files into the configuration admin via its interface.

As an alternative, the Felix configuration admin service allows you to plug-in your own persister solution to read and write the configurations. An implementation of a persister that uses property files can be found [here](http://www.avineas.org/index.php?page=cm-persister). It is a very basic persister and specifically written for the Felix configuration admin implementation.

Comment: thanks, main problem is "how can we do it within an netbeans platform?"

Comment: You need to enlighten us a little on your main problem and what you mean with "it". From the post I got the impression that you got your bundles, including a configuration manager, already up and running. In that case it would mean to write/add an additional bundle that helps in loading the property files.

Comment: Yes, i have bundles , and i want one of the them to be configurable(via a configuration file). Another difference is that i run these bundles on a Netbeans Platform Application which runs an embedded felix osgi container inside. How can i access embedded felix inside the netbeans platform app.

Comment: If you want to do your bundle configuration via the configuration admin, read the appropriate specification in Configuration Admin chapter and the Declared Services chapter from the OSGi specifications. About embedded Felix: although I never did this in Netbeans, there is nothing special about embedding an OSGi container. You just load the bundles into that container and read the configuration from disk. You don't have anything to do with Netbeans, why do you want to access Felix from Netbeans?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually this question is mostly related with Netbeans platform. I think there is a something wrong with understanding of the problem. I do know how to use OSGi Config Admin service. But the real problem is file management via Netbeans&Felix. I use Netbeans RCP platform and Felix together for developing an application. Netbeans RCP Platform is something like framework, SDK for developing rich client applications.

Comment: It may be that the problem is not well understood. Will you be able to edit the post and provide more detail to give us and others to a better understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution (there are many others as @arivanw explains) is to use Apache FileInstall. It can be used to define configurations in .cfg files and instal then when you put them in a magic folder. They're uninstalled when you remove them from that folder.

Comment: main problem is "how can we do it within an netbeans platform?"

Comment: Start with installing the Apache Fileinstall bundle?

Comment: OK, i'll give it try. But i i run these bundles on a Netbeans Platform Application which runs an embedded felix osgi container inside. Main focus is that how can i access embedded felix inside the netbeans platform app.